# Adwords API Modify class in order to pass a variable and get response in variable

Tags: php, api, class, google-ads-api

I'm trying to modify a class given from a PHP script example from the Adwords API.

I'm pretty new to playing with Objects in PHP so I can't figure out how to make it work.

I would like to modify this script below in order to pass on a keyword array as a variable, therefore replacing the keywords contained in:

```
$relatedToQuerySearchParameter->setQueries([
        'bakery', 'pastries', 'birthday cake'
    ]);
```

Maybe to use it as a function will normally do :

```
function GetKeywordIdeas($array_keywords){...}
```

And then get the results in a variable

Here's the code from the example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
namespace Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201710\Optimization;

require __DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\Language;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\NetworkSetting;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\Paging;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\AttributeType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\IdeaType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\LanguageSearchParameter;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\NetworkSearchParameter;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\RelatedToQuerySearchParameter;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\RequestType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\SeedAdGroupIdSearchParameter;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\TargetingIdeaSelector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\TargetingIdeaService;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\Util\MapEntries;

/**
 * This example gets keyword ideas related to a seed keyword.
 */
class GetKeywordIdeas {

  // If you do not want to use an existing ad group to seed your request, you
  // can set this to null.
  const AD_GROUP_ID = 'INSERT_AD_GROUP_ID_HERE';
  const PAGE_LIMIT = 500;

  public static function runExample(AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
      AdWordsSession $session, $adGroupId) {
    $targetingIdeaService =
        $adWordsServices->get($session, TargetingIdeaService::class);

    // Create selector.
    $selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
    $selector->setRequestType(RequestType::IDEAS);
    $selector->setIdeaType(IdeaType::KEYWORD);
    $selector->setRequestedAttributeTypes([
        AttributeType::KEYWORD_TEXT,
        AttributeType::SEARCH_VOLUME,
        AttributeType::AVERAGE_CPC,
        AttributeType::COMPETITION,
        AttributeType::CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES
    ]);

    $paging = new Paging();
    $paging->setStartIndex(0);
    $paging->setNumberResults(10);
    $selector->setPaging($paging);

    $searchParameters = [];
    // Create related to query search parameter.
    $relatedToQuerySearchParameter = new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter();
    $relatedToQuerySearchParameter->setQueries([
        'bakery', 'pastries', 'birthday cake'
    ]);
    $searchParameters[] = $relatedToQuerySearchParameter;

    // Create language search parameter (optional).
    // The ID can be found in the documentation:
    // https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/languagecodes
    $languageParameter = new LanguageSearchParameter();
    $english = new Language();
    $english->setId(1000);
    $languageParameter->setLanguages([$english]);
    $searchParameters[] = $languageParameter;

    // Create network search parameter (optional).
    $networkSetting = new NetworkSetting();
    $networkSetting->setTargetGoogleSearch(true);
    $networkSetting->setTargetSearchNetwork(false);
    $networkSetting->setTargetContentNetwork(false);
    $networkSetting->setTargetPartnerSearchNetwork(false);

    $networkSearchParameter = new NetworkSearchParameter();
    $networkSearchParameter->setNetworkSetting($networkSetting);
    $searchParameters[] = $networkSearchParameter;

    // Optional: Use an existing ad group to generate ideas.
    if (!empty($adGroupId)) {
      $seedAdGroupIdSearchParameter = new SeedAdGroupIdSearchParameter();
      $seedAdGroupIdSearchParameter->setAdGroupId($adGroupId);
      $searchParameters[] = $seedAdGroupIdSearchParameter;
    }
    $selector->setSearchParameters($searchParameters);
    $selector->setPaging(new Paging(0, self::PAGE_LIMIT));

    // Get keyword ideas.
    $page = $targetingIdeaService->get($selector);

    // Print out some information for each targeting idea.
    $entries = $page->getEntries();
    if ($entries !== null) {
      foreach ($entries as $targetingIdea) {
        $data = MapEntries::toAssociativeArray($targetingIdea->getData());
        $keyword = $data[AttributeType::KEYWORD_TEXT]->getValue();
        $searchVolume =
            ($data[AttributeType::SEARCH_VOLUME]->getValue() !== null)
            ? $data[AttributeType::SEARCH_VOLUME]->getValue() : 0;
        $averageCpc = $data[AttributeType::AVERAGE_CPC]->getValue();
        $competition = $data[AttributeType::COMPETITION]->getValue();
        $categoryIds =
            ($data[AttributeType::CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES]->getValue()
                === null)
            ? $categoryIds = '' : implode(
                ', ',
                $data[AttributeType::CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES]->getValue()
            );
        printf(
            "Keyword with text '%s', average monthly search volume %d, "
                . "average CPC %d, and competition %.2f "
                . "was found with categories: %s\n",
            $keyword,
            $searchVolume,
            ($averageCpc === null) ? 0 : $averageCpc->getMicroAmount(),
            $competition,
            $categoryIds
        );
      }
    }

    if (empty($entries)) {
      print "No related keywords were found.\n";
    }
  }

  public static function main() {
    // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->build();

    // Construct an API session configured from a properties file and the OAuth2
    // credentials above.
    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();
    self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session, self::AD_GROUP_ID);
  }
}

GetKeywordIdeas::main();
```

Thanks for your help or explanations.

Comment: which part exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: The class GetKeywordIdeas only echoes the result of some keywords given in an array which is given in the class itself. I don't have any clues how I can transform this class in order to pass the keywords from a variable.

Comment: This maybe very simple (or not), just that I never played with OOP code before

Comment: I tried to answer below, not quite sure if it´s what you were asking for. just let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change 4 lines in the code. 1.

```
  public static function main() {
```

to

```
public static function main($array_keywords) {
```

and 2.

```
self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session, self::AD_GROUP_ID);
```

to

```
self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session, self::AD_GROUP_ID, $array_keywords);
```

and 3.

```
 public static function runExample(AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
  AdWordsSession $session, $adGroupId) {
```

to

```
 public static function runExample(AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
  AdWordsSession $session, $adGroupId, $array_keywords) {
```

and 4.

```
    $relatedToQuerySearchParameter->setQueries([
    'bakery', 'pastries', 'birthday cake'
]);
```

to

```
    $relatedToQuerySearchParameter->setQueries($array_keywords);
```

then you can call it like this:

```
GetKeywordIdeas::main($array_keywords);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work as what I'm trying to do is to define the array of keywords from outside the class. In this example, the result is echoed with the line : GetKeywordIdeas::main(); . I'm not sure how to modify this in order to write something like : GetKeywordIdeas($array_keywords)::main();

Comment: ok, got it. I updated the code, please take a look. see if it works, and let me know if there´s something you don´t understand

Comment: It works just perfectly, many thanks !!! Last question, is there any way I can get the result not echoed how it's done now with "printf" but to get the result in a variable such as something like : $keywords = GetKeywordIdeas::main($array_keywords);

Comment: yes, sure. it won´t fit in the comments, I´ll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

answer to a comment, returning the keywords as an array:

you will need to insert and change several lines:

before this line:

```
foreach ($entries as $targetingIdea) {
```

insert

```
$keywords = [];
```

after `$keyword = $data[AttributeType::KEYWORD_TEXT]->getValue();`
insert `$keywords[] = $keyword;`

before these lines

```
    }
if (empty($entries)) {
```

insert `return $keywords;`

change `self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session, self::AD_GROUP_ID, $array_keywords);`

to `return self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session, self::AD_GROUP_ID, $array_keywords);`

then call it like this `$keywords = GetKeywordIdeas::main($array_keywords);`

Comment: this is quick & dirty, let me know if it doesn´t work

Comment: Great ! This will do the trick, (I passed the array to set the variable). Thank you Musashii you saved my day !!!

Comment: nice! happy to help :)